# HTML Book Compiler

Tags: html, bash

I have written a BASH script to parse and compile HTML code into a single page. The script works as expected, although my code is not completely re-usable and the standard output messages could be more helpful.

Besides my intended improvements, are there any other problems with my code?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Append each section of the book from each retrieved webpage


function help
{
    cat << EOF
This script compiles a book from the 'content' element found in multiple pages.    
Written by Ben Cottrell.

Usage: $0 [pages] [output]

EOF
}

function compile
{
    LIST=$(cat $1)
    FILENAME=""
    OUTPUT=$2

    cat << HEADER > $OUTPUT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Generated at $(date) -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
        <title>Template</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
HEADER

    mkdir _pages

    for PAGE in $LIST; do
        echo $PAGE
        wget -q --directory-prefix="_pages/" $PAGE
        #Append the entry
        if [ $? == 0 ]; then
                #Extracts the title from a tag within a retrieved HTML document    
                FILENAME=$(basename $PAGE)
                cat << CONTENT>> $OUTPUT
                <h3>$(xmllint --html --xpath '/html/head/title/text()' "_pages/$FILENAME")</h3>
                <a href="$PAGE">Retrieved from $PAGE</a>
                <div class="section">
                $(xmllint --html --xpath "//div[@id='content']/node()" "_pages/$FILENAME")
                </div>
CONTENT
        else
               cat << SECTION >> $OUTPUT
                <h3>$(basename $PAGE)</h3>
                <div class="section">
                Unavailable
                </div>
SECTION
        fi
    done

    cat << FINAL >> $OUTPUT
    </body>
</html> 
FINAL

}


if [ $# == 2 ]; then
    #Check if the 'xmllint' executable and the files exist
    if [ ! $(which xmllint) ]; then
        cat << EOF
       The xmllint executable is missing from your system.
       Please install the program first, before using this script.
EOF
    fi

    if [ -x $1 ]; then
        echo "A file containing a list of URL's is missing."
    fi
    compile $1 $2
else
    help
fi
```

Comment: This is kind of a cool concept, and I understand what's happening... I feel good reading this :P

Answer (score 6):

Copy paste your code on [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/#), it will give you some interesting recommendations.

Among other things, interestingly, it points out a parsing error for this:

> ```
> cat << CONTENT>> $OUTPUT
> ```

Though it actually works for me as it is, it's better to add a space after "CONTENT" to make it clear, like this:

```
cat << CONTENT >> $OUTPUT
```

---

When declaring functions, instead of this:

> ```
> function help
> {
> ```

The modern convention is this writing style:

```
help() {
```

---

The here-documents disrupt the logical flow of the script, for example here:

> ```
>     if [ ! $(which xmllint) ]; then
>         cat << EOF
>        The xmllint executable is missing from your system.
>        Please install the program first, before using this script.
> EOF
>     fi
> ```

You can mitigate that disruption by moving the printing logic to a helper function.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [@janos's points](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/98219/78894):

### `cat` vs `echo`:

You've used quite a few HEREDOCs in this script, some of them pretty short. I'd tend to use `echo` for these instead, which not only makes it more explicit that the output is a string, but keeps it all inline, e.g.:

```
    cat << EOF
   The xmllint executable is missing from your system.
   Please install the program first, before using this script.
EOF
```

could be converted to:

```
echo "The xmllint executable is missing from your system."
echo "Please install the program first, before using this script."
```

You could also move these messages out into separate variables, which would also minimise their impact on the script.

This also has the questionable benefit that you're not relying on an external program to do the printing, since `echo` is a bash built-in.

### Tests

Strictly speaking, when used with `[`, the use of `==` is a bashism which is not portable to other shells. Even in bash, it's the operator intended for use when comparing **strings**, rather than numbers.

Use `=` for strings, and `-eq` for bare numbers, and check `help test` for other test operators.

This brings me on to:

```
if [ -x $1 ]; then
    echo "A file containing a list of URL's is missing."
fi
```

I'm not quite sure why you're checking whether your file of URLs is executable. If you just want to check whether it exists, you want the `-a` operator, but it's a little more effective to check whether it exists and is readable, which is `-r`.

As [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) says, you should also double-quote these variables: this stops things like filenames with spaces breaking your script, and also forces empty variables to expand to empty strings, rather than expanding to nothing at all and causing syntax errors.

### Errors

In a few places you've printed out error messages, but the script doesn't *stop*, it carries on regardless. Is this intentional?

Also, error messages should, in general, go to `stderr`.

I tend to define some exit codes and do something like:

```
# Define these all in one place
ERR_INVALID_ARGS=5

#Then later, if args are invalid
echo "Error: invalid arguments provided" >&2 # redirects to stderr
exit $ERR_INVALID_ARGS
```

### More general stuff

You could, if you wanted, make the output a command-line option using `getopt`, allow any number of input files as an argument using a while loop and `shift`, and output to `stdout` by default.

You might also want to check whether the file exists before you write to it, and you could do something like `read` a Y/N check whether you want to overwrite, rather than always appending.

None of the above is really a big problem here. The script is reasonably structured, and your biggest worry (IMO) is that you could expand an empty variable and get a syntax error, or accidentally screw up an existing file.

Comment: `echo -e` is not a good recommendation, because the flags of `echo` are not portable. `printf` is more portable.

Comment: @janos: Good point, POSIX standards don't require the `-e` option (it's in both the GNU version of `/bin/echo` and the `bash` version, but not the `dash` version, for example). Removed it.